# Anaconda : Unable to launch Jupyter Lab 2.6

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I am getting the below error message when trying to launch Jupyter Lab , not able to figure out what could be the issue.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\timing.py", line 27, in 
import resource
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't launch Jupyter Notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60966135/cant-launch-jupyter-notebook-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-resource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had faced the same problem, I opened the CMD.exe from the Anaconda Navigator and executed below command:

```
conda update --all
```

This solved my problem